# Link on a fixed area above a background-position:cover background image

Tags: html, css, dictionary, imagemap

I have [this](http://goo.gl/XiXWx) landing page. I'd like the email to be a link to mailto:info@domain.tld.

I tried to use a map (usemap="#mail" on body and then map name="mail">) but it doesn't work. I tried also with a blank transparent png image (to set the usemap to) but the link isn't clickable.

How can I achieve the area of the email to have a link upon it? Of course it should work on different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just render the email link as text? It looks like it can be similar to Open Sans: http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans

Comment: Uhm, but how can I be sure it's positioned right there? The background-image has a background-size:cover.

Comment: The background-size:cover seems to be based off the width. If you have the position of the text set using a % based right margin, it should move in tandem with your background image.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

ADD CSS:

```
div#mail {
margin-left: 67%;
margin-top: 31.8%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 16%;
}

a {
color: transparent;
}
```

ADD HTML:

```
<div id="mail"><a href="mailto:info@gioiellidisapone.it">info@gioiellidisapone.it</a></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fXats/

It's not perfect, but maybe it's good enough. :)

Comment: Mario Vlad and @robx If I resize the window the text goes up:
http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/2561/gioiellidisapone.png

Comment: Does not move for me. It is most likely moving because you want a fluid layout. Your image seems to scale as well, so if you make it a fixed width and height, then it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I modified your page directly using Inspect element, and the link stays on top of the image text. This is another option, but has fixed width and height to support the positioning of the email.

```
<body>
<div style="
    width: 1430px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 700px;
    background-image: url(home2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    display: inline-block;
"><a href="#" style="
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
    right: 294px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
">Info@gioiellidisapone.it</a>
</div>
</body>
```